# Script runs and stops immediately

Tags: python

I ran this program on Repl.it for forking purposes - Peculiar enough, it does not seem to work, as Repl.it automatically runs then stops the program.

```
found = False
i = 0 

capital = ["London","New Dehli","Jerusalem","Paris","Washington DC","Riyadh","Kaula Lumpur"]

user_search = ("Which capital do you wish to search for \n - ")
while found == False and i < len(capital):
  if user_search == capital[i]:
    print ("Capital found")
    found = True
  i= i+1
```

Comment: why not use `if user_search in capital:`? also you forgot to get the input from the user `user_search = input("What capital...")`

Comment: `user_search` is a simple string - it is not contained within the capitals array.  thus the `i` variable is incremented up to 7 (the number of items in your array) then program ends.

Comment: @I.Abbas make sure you fix the other main issue of getting user input

Comment: @sniperd There is meant to be an output if you entered in one of the cities stated on the list.

Comment: UPDATE : I was being a bit stupid and forgot my input. Thanks for your help @depperm

Comment: ah, I see, OK, I'll toss an answer in.

Comment: found = False
i = 0 

capital = ["London","New Dehli","Jerusalem","Paris","Washington DC","Riyadh","Kaula Lumpur"]

user_search = input("Which capital do you wish to search for \n - ")
while found == False and i < len(capital):
  if user_search == capital[i]:
    print ("Capital found")
    found = True
  i= i+1

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting the input, so change it like so:

```
user_search = input("Which capital do you wish to search for \n - ")
```

With proper indentation, spacing and correct spelling, it should be:

```
found = False
i = 0 
capital = ["London", "New Delhi", "Jerusalem", "Paris", "Washington DC", "Riyadh", "Kuala Lumpur"]

user_search = input("Which capital do you wish to search for \n - ")

while found == False and i < len(capital):
    if user_search == capital[i]:
        print("Capital found")
        found = True
    i = i + 1
```

If you could do without the `while` loop, like others said, you could just use an `if statement` with the membership operator `in`.

```
capital = ["London", "New Delhi", "Jerusalem", "Paris", "Washington DC", "Riyadh", "Kuala Lumpur"]
user_search = input("Which capital do you wish to search for \n - ")

if user_search in capital:
    print("Capital found")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to output anything you'll need to ask for input, and I would suggest not doing the while loop, you can look for a string in a list as follows:

```
capital = ["London","New Dehli","Jerusalem","Paris","Washington DC","Riyadh","Kaula Lumpur"]
user_search = input("Which capital do you wish to search for \n - ")
if user_search in capital:
    print ("found it")
```